# JWT Token no se guarda en el header

Tags: nodejs, angular, api, jwt, headers

Estoy intentando almacenar un Jason Web Token en mi header para la autenticación de rutas en una API, pero el token no está siendo almacenado en el header, ya he revisado la composición del método del servicio en angular y todo está correcto, pero aun así sigue sin funcionar, el token si esta siendo almacenado la respectiva variable porque ya lo he impreso en un console.log e incluso se visualiza en la request que se envia al API para que posteriormente sea almacenado en el header, reitero al final sin exito alguno, quisiera saber si es posible una ayuda, proporciono imagenes de mi codigo:

Servicio de Angular desde el cual se visualiza que se le esta pasando el parametro token con el JWT del usuario logueado al metodo para acceder a la ruta del API:

```
  fetchClients(tipo: any, filtro: any, token: any): Observable<any> {
    let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json').set('Authorization', token);
    return this._http.post(this.url + 'listarClientes/' + tipo + '/' + filtro, { headers: headers });
  }
```

Ruta en NodeJS a la cual se accede desde el servicio de Angular, se visualiza que esta se encuentra protegida con el middleware importado y almacenado en la variable authJwt:

```
api.post('/listarClientes/:tipo/:filtro?', authJwt.auth, clienteController.fetchClients);
```

Metodo de autenticación del middleware en NodeJS desde el cual se valida la existencia del elemento con clave Authorization en el header (gracias a este metodo evidencio no se almacena el token en el header):

```
exports.auth = function(req, res, next){
    console.log(req.headers.Authorization);
    if(!req.headers.Authorization){
        return res.status(403).send({message: req.headers});
    }

    var token = req.headers.authorization.replace(/['"]+/g,'');
    var segmentToken = token.split('.');

    if(segmentToken.length != 3){
        return res.status(403).send({message: 'InvalidToken'});
    }else{
        try {
            var payload = jwt.decode(token,secret);
            
            if(payload.exp <= moment.unix){
                return res.status(403).send({message: 'ExpiredToken'});
            }

        } catch (error) {
            return res.status(403).send({message: 'InvalidToken'});
        }
    }

    req.user = payload;

    next();
```

Request de cuando se ejecuta la petición y se visualiza el token en la misma:

```
XHRPOSThttp://127.0.0.1:4201/api/listarClientes/null/null
[HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden 45ms]

{"headers":{"normalizedNames":{},"lazyUpdate":[{"name":"Content-Type","value":"application/json","op":"s"},{"name":"Authorization","value":"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiI2MmQwZGYzYWMxMDVlNmVhOTc4NmRiNmEiLCJub21icmVzIjoiTmljb2xhcyIsImFwZWxsaWRvcyI6IkVzdGV2ZXoiLCJlbWFpbCI6InBsb3BzdGVyY2VvQHBsb3BzdGVyLmNvbS5jbyIsInJvbCI6ImFkbWluIiwiaWF0IjoxNjU4NjA1Mjk3LCJleHAiOjE2NTkyMTAwOTd9.8QNUo4lQDEYgVqbJ9UxYuj-YG1yKAN5eQvTq7CCorcQ","op":"s"}],"headers":{},"lazyInit":{"normalizedNames":{},"lazyUpdate":null,"headers":{}}}}
```

Impresión en consola de los headers una vez se ejecuta el metodo de autenticacion para validar el token(Aqui tambien evidencio que el toquen cargado en la request no se almacena en el header ya que no hay ningun elemento con la clave Authorization):

```
  host: '127.0.0.1:4201',
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:102.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/102.0',
  origin: 'http://localhost:4200',
  connection: 'keep-alive',
  referer: 'http://localhost:4200/',
  'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
  'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
  'sec-fetch-site': 'cross-site'
```

Al igual que en la prueba anterior al intentar imprimir `req.headers.Authorization` en el metodo de autenticación obtengo la siguiente respuesta de mi API:

```
Undefined
```

Agradecería me lograran ayudar :D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El inconveniente fue solucionado validando desde el middleware, evidencié que al momento en el que Angular envía los elementos a nodeJS express al parecer transforma la información a Lower Case, por lo tanto, yo al validar el elemento Authorization el API me devolvia undefined porque el dato se almacenaba como authorization.

```
exports.auth = function(req, res, next){
    if(!req.headers.authorization){
        return res.status(403).send({message: req.headers});
    }

    var token = req.headers.authorization.replace(/['"]+/g,'');
    var segmentToken = token.split('.');

    if(segmentToken.length != 3){
        return res.status(403).send({message: 'InvalidToken'});
    }else{
        try {
            var payload = jwt.decode(token,secret);
            
            if(payload.exp <= moment.unix){
                return res.status(403).send({message: 'ExpiredToken'});
            }

        } catch (error) {
            return res.status(403).send({message: 'InvalidTokenDOS'});
        }
    }

    req.user = payload;

    next();
}
```

Muchas gracias a todos por su ayuda y colaboración.

Answer (score 1):

La firma del método post es la siguiente:

```
httpClient.post(url, body, options)
```

Por lo que en tu caso como tienes el objeto de las opciones con los headers como segundo argumento en vez del tercero, este objeto se esta pasando en el cuerpo del mensaje y por eso no te funciona.

---

Dicho esto, para las peticiones de consulta en las que solo obtienes información, como parece que es el caso, deberías usar el método `GET`.

En la firma del método get del httpClient las opciones son el segundo parámetro:

```
httpClient.get(url, options)
```

Así que en ese caso no tendrías que modificar nada más que el nombre del método en el código que tienes actualmente.

un saludo

Answer (score 1):

> Cada vez que el usuario desee acceder a una ruta o recurso protegido,
> debe enviar el JWT, generalmente en el encabezado
> de Autorización utilizando el esquema Bearer. El contenido del
> encabezado debe ser similar al siguiente:

```
Authorization: Bearer <token>
```

lo utilizaremos como:

```
const headers = new Headers({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': `Bearer ${auth_token}`
  })
```

eviandolo en las peticion por ejemplo como:

```
this.http.get(apiUrl, { headers: headers })
```

en nodejs

```
exports.auth = async(req, res, next) => {
  const token = req.header('Authorization').replace('Bearer ', '')
.....
.....
}
```